# ImportError using pip install on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, importerror

I installed a module called `mrjob` using `sudo pip install mrjob`. When I start python and try to import it, I get `ImportError: No module named mrjob`.

Using `iname`, I find out that `mrjob` is installed in `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, while all my Python modules are in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. So I add the new folder to my PATH with `export PATH=/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PATH`.

But even after I do that, I still get `ImportError`. If I `cd` to `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and start python from there, it imports the module correctly.

I also tried to uninstall the module:

```
> sudo pip uninstall mrjob
Password:
Cannot uninstall requirement mrjob, not installed
```

If I do:

```
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

The folder `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` isn't there.

**== UPDATE ==**

The following command worked

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/usr/local" mrjob
```

I can now import `mrjob` correctly. But I still don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem too. Cause python use the system pre-install python at

```
/Libarary/Python
```

But this python without pip. while I install pip, it will install at

```
/usr/local/Libarary/Python
```

My solution is install pip for the system by this:

```
sudo easy_install -U pip
```